# preposition usage of "with"

Tags: prepositions

Fill the blank with the answer:

> But the epidemic is "moderate" in severity, according to Margaret Chan, the organization's director general, ____ the overwhelming majority of patients experiencing only mild symptoms and a full recovery, often in the absence of any medical treatment.
>
> A. with
> B. in
> C. from
> D. by

Hello guys, the right answer is **A**, but I wonder why it can be?

According to this link([preposisions](https://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/prepositions-with-over-by.aspx)), there introduces the situation where the **with** can be used, that is, **with** is used to indicate **together**, **using**, **having**, **feeling**, and **agreement**.

In above blank, Does it belongs to the **having** case? If not, I would like to consult you which and why? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resource you are linking to is not really representative of the full range of expressions where you can use "with". There are idioms where "with" governs an entire phrase as background or explanation for a statement.

> They were divided into two groups, with no girls in one group and no boys in the other.
> (Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/with)

and perhaps in particular

> I'm very tired, what with travelling all day yesterday and having a disturbed night.
> (Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/what-with)

Though the first example is actually provided as an example of *"with"* meaning *"having",* I feel that that's stretching the definition a bit. It's more obvious, at least, in concrete phrases like "a shirt with many colors". Perhaps see also [Use of "having" and 'with'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/101092/use-of-having-and-with)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I read your first link and learn a lot. You said `There are idioms where "with" governs an entire phrase as background or explanation for a statement.`.  Do you means the **with** in the blank should be the `because of or caused by someone or something:` case of **with** rather than `having` case? Hopefully I do not misunderstand. And sorry, but why you provide the second link about **what-with**?

Comment: The second example shows a particular idiom where _with_ is basically always used with an entire phrase as, uh, the thing which the preceding statement relates to.

Comment: Perhaps rephrase the example from your question as "Because of the overwhelming majority of patients experiencing only mild symptoms and a full recovery, often in the absence of any medical treatment, the epidemic is 'moderate' in severity, according to Margaret Chan." In other words, the "with" governs everything after it in the original example sentence.

Comment: Thank you, learn a lot today!